# Can I use cancellationToken == CancellationToken.None to check for default(CancellationToken)

Tags: c#

The reason is that if it is `CancellationToken.None`, I need to add a timeout (so a new `CancellationToken` from `CancellationTokenSource`), for example

```
if (cancellationToken == CancellationToken.None)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    tokenSource.CancelAfter((int)_timeout.TotalMilliseconds);

    cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
}
```

the other idea is to create a combined token.

**Update.** Would something like this work? Any issues I should be aware of? Will GC do what it needs to?

```
public async Task<int> InternalActionAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    // do something with the token...
    return 1;
}

public Task<int> ExternalActionAsync(CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var internalTokenSource = 
            new CancellationTokenSource((int)_timeout.TotalMilliseconds);
    var linkedTokenSource = 
            CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token, 
                                                            internalTokenSource.Token);

    return InternalActionAsync(linkedTokenSource.Token);
}
```

Comment: I think that will work, but seems odd given the user didn't initiate the cancellation yet the task is cancelled.

Comment: That's true. I'm trying to add a TimeOut which is missing in Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient compared to the System.Net HttpClient.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(default(System.Threading.CancellationToken) == System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);`
produces "True"

Answer (score 7):

First of all, looking at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs,ec32c41597007382):

```
public static CancellationToken None
{
    get { return default(CancellationToken); }
}
```

So you can be safe to assume they're equal.

But, if the user doesn't have a `CancellationToken` to pass, perhaps you could request a `CancellationToken?` instead of relying on default equality between the tokens:

```
public Task<int> ExternalActionAsync(CancellationToken? token = null)
{
    if (token == null)
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        tokenSource.CancelAfter((int)_timeout.TotalMilliseconds);
        token = tokenSource.Token;
    }

    return InternalActionAsync(token);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the default value of a `CancellationToken` with `CancellationToken.None` and it will result `true`. The default `CancellationToken` has no token source, and `CancellationToken.None` gives back the default value, too. When you compare the two values, what will happen is that the comparison sees that none of the values have token source, and treats them as equal.

`CancellationTokens` are value types, the only GC issue could be the referenced token source - but default cancellation tokens have no token source.

Regarding your second solution, in case of default cancellation token, it will not really link them, it will ignore the default token (no token source, so it cannot subscribe to its cancellation). I cannot see any issue with this solution.